# How to rotate image with 3D effect?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-animation, 3d, image-rotation

I want to rotate the .gif image with 3D effect in iPhone application,can anyone help me to provide the sample code or any direction is also appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters I think @Brad Larsons website will help you (or his projects).

http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2009/01/13/opengl-es-catransform3d